# Classification of Orbits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Describe the orbits of $$\frac{{\rm d}r}{{\rm d}t}=r(r-2)(r-4),$$ where $(r,t)$ is
the usual polar co-ordinates.

Can we do solve this problem without integration? What is meant by 'describe' here?
I am trying to use the Cantor-Bendixon Theorem , but I cannot really solve it.

Comment: Hint: Think of it as a one-dimensional dynamical system, where $t$ is time, and draw the phase portrait on the $r$ axis.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [W|A](http://tinyurl.com/c9ck9cf)...